# Session lifetime in client server environment outside ASP.NET

Tags: nhibernate, ninject

We heavily rely upon injection mechanism with Ninject. Currently we struggle how to handle sessions. We read a lot about session management and we want to implement session per business conversion. We have a simple infrastructure like the following:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    public Repository(ISession session)
    {
        this.Session = session;
    }

    protected ISession Session { get; private set; }

    public TEntity FindBy(Guid key)
    {
        return this.Session.Get<TEntity>(key);
    }
    /// rest omitted
}
```

A consumer of a repo looks like the following:

```
    public class Consumer {
            public Consumer (Repository<SomeEntity> repo, ISession session)
            public void DoSomeWork() {
                    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction()) {
                       repo.FindBy(someId);
                       /// etc.
                       tx.Commit();
            }
    }
```

The ISession injected in the Repo instance is guaranteed to be the same as the ISession in the consumer. We are building a little server application which internally hosts several infrastructure services which have the lifetime of the server process and some WCF endpoints. As we are controlling milling machines the infrastructure services are mainly here to control the creation and proper disposal of the "software" machines and their state machines.

We were thinking about the following session management structure:

- Infrastructure services: Session per Service
- WCF endpoints: Session per OperationContext
- Other components: ?

For some cases the WCF endpoints need to hook into the infrastructure services. How would you handle the sessions there?

Any advice?

Comment: Regarding the deactivation aspect. @Remo Gloor has work in train for 2.4 re automatic deactivation as per ASP.NET based on the Scope as you'll run into memory usage/OutOfMemory exceptions - you on a branch that has the reworked/generalized WCF context management extensions? (I know this has little to do with the session management that's your real question but I reckon it's important to factor this aspect into your considerations)

Answer (score 0):

if you use session per service endpoint then all the consumers of that service would be using the same session. that's not advisable.
personally I'd go with session-per-request, as it's much easier to use and implement, and your question didn't indicate any justification for using anything else.
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867457/session-per-request-implementation-for-wcf-nhibernate-and-ninject) for further detail.

Comment: using OperationContext as scope is the same as per request

Comment: but not every process which needs data from the database is started from a user interaction. For example when the system starts up some of the infrastructure services need to query for configured machine data. How would you solve that? Session per singleton service? But I read that this is not advised because the session would be living too long.

Comment: in those cases you might consider calling your 'per request' code explicitly.